# seam generate entities and ui isnt working

Tags: seam

i am using seam 2.2.0 GA and i have created a project and try to generate entities and ui
but it doesnt work and it doesnt show any relevant errors,

here is the output, what am i missing?,

any help please

thanks a lot.

```
SEAM_HOME: C:\java\opt\jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA
Using seam-gen sources from: C:\java\opt\jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA\seam-gen
Buildfile: C:\java\opt\jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA\seam-gen\build.xml

init:

init-properties:
 [echo] C:/java/opt/jboss-as-4.2.2.GA

validate-workspace:

validate-project:

init-generate:

generate-model:
     [echo] Reverse engineering database using JDBC driver C:/java/lib/mysql-con
nector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
     [echo] project=C:/Documents and Settings/dmolina/My Documents/My Dropbox/Pr
ojects/Acciones
     [echo] model=org.cocesna.Acciones.model
[hibernate] Executing Hibernate Tool with a JDBC Configuration (for reverse engi
neering)
[hibernate] 1. task: hbm2java (Generates a set of .java files)
[hibernate] 11:12:15,109  INFO Environment:543 - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
[hibernate] 11:12:15,109  INFO Environment:576 - hibernate.properties not found
[hibernate] 11:12:15,109  INFO Environment:709 - Bytecode provider name : javass
ist
[hibernate] 11:12:15,125  INFO Environment:627 - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestam
p handling
[hibernate] 11:12:15,250  INFO OverrideRepository:113 - Override file: C:\Docume
nts and Settings\dmolina\My Documents\My Dropbox\Projects\Acciones\resources\sea
m-gen.reveng.xml
[hibernate] 11:12:15,313  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:64 - Using Hibern
ate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
[hibernate] 11:12:15,328  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:65 - Hibernate co
nnection pool size: 20
[hibernate] 11:12:15,328  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:68 - autocommit m
ode: false
[hibernate] 11:12:15,328  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:103 - using drive
r: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acciones
[hibernate] 11:12:15,328  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:109 - connection
properties: {user=root, dataSource_class=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlData
Source, password=****}
[hibernate] 11:12:15,578  INFO SettingsFactory:116 - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.1.
41
[hibernate] 11:12:15,578  INFO SettingsFactory:117 - JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC
Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.13 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
[hibernate] 11:12:15,610  INFO Dialect:175 - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialec
t.MySQLDialect
[hibernate] 11:12:15,641  INFO TransactionFactoryFactory:59 - Using default tran
saction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
[hibernate] 11:12:15,641  INFO TransactionManagerLookupFactory:80 - No Transacti
onManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transaction
al second-level cache is not recommended)
[hibernate] 11:12:15,641  INFO SettingsFactory:170 - Automatic flush during befo
reCompletion(): disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,641  INFO SettingsFactory:174 - Automatic session close at
end of transaction: disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,641  INFO SettingsFactory:181 - JDBC batch size: 15
[hibernate] 11:12:15,641  INFO SettingsFactory:184 - JDBC batch updates for vers
ioned data: disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:189 - Scrollable result sets: ena
bled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:197 - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): e
nabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:205 - Connection release mode: au
to
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:224 - Default catalog: PUBLIC
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:229 - Maximum outer join fetch de
pth: 2
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:232 - Default batch fetch size: 1

[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:236 - Generate SQL with comments:
 disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:240 - Order SQL updates by primar
y key: disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:244 - Order SQL inserts for batch
ing: disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO SettingsFactory:420 - Query translator: org.hiber
nate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
[hibernate] 11:12:15,656  INFO ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - Using ASTQueryTran
slatorFactory
[hibernate] 11:12:15,672  INFO SettingsFactory:252 - Query language substitution
s: {}
[hibernate] 11:12:15,672  INFO SettingsFactory:257 - JPA-QL strict compliance: d
isabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,672  INFO SettingsFactory:262 - Second-level cache: enabled

[hibernate] 11:12:15,672  INFO SettingsFactory:266 - Query cache: disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,672  INFO SettingsFactory:405 - Cache region factory : org.
hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge
[hibernate] 11:12:15,672  INFO RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge:61 - Cache provi
der: org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
[hibernate] 11:12:15,672  INFO SettingsFactory:276 - Optimize cache for minimal
puts: disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,672  INFO SettingsFactory:285 - Structured second-level cac
he entries: disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,688  INFO SettingsFactory:314 - Statistics: disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,688  INFO SettingsFactory:318 - Deleted entity synthetic id
entifier rollback: disabled
[hibernate] 11:12:15,688  INFO SettingsFactory:333 - Default entity-mode: pojo
[hibernate] 11:12:15,688  INFO SettingsFactory:337 - Named query checking : enab
led
[hibernate] 11:12:15,719  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:170 - cleaning up
 connection pool: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acciones
[hibernate] 11:12:15,766  INFO Version:15 - Hibernate Tools 3.2.4.GA
[javaformatter] Java formatting of 0 files completed. Skipped 0 file(s).

generate-ui:
     [echo] Building project 'Acciones' to generate views and controllers

init:

groovy.compilemodel:

compilemodel:

groovy.compileactions:

groovy.copyactions:

compileactions:

copyclasses:

compile:

war:
[hibernate] Executing Hibernate Tool with a JPA Configuration
[hibernate] 1. task: generic exportertemplate: view/list.xhtml.ftl
[hibernate] 11:12:16,141  INFO Version:15 - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
[hibernate] 11:12:16,141  INFO Version:14 - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.
GA
[hibernate] 11:12:16,156  INFO Version:16 - Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0.GA
[hibernate] 2. task: generic exportertemplate: view/view.xhtml.ftl
[hibernate] 3. task: generic exportertemplate: view/view.page.xml.ftl
[hibernate] 4. task: generic exportertemplate: view/edit.xhtml.ftl
[hibernate] 5. task: generic exportertemplate: view/edit.page.xml.ftl
[hibernate] 6. task: generic exportertemplate: src/EntityList.java.ftl
[hibernate] 7. task: generic exportertemplate: view/list.page.xml.ftl
[hibernate] 8. task: generic exportertemplate: src/EntityHome.java.ftl
[hibernate] 9. task: generic exportertemplate: view/layout/menu.xhtml.ftl
[javaformatter] Java formatting of 1 files completed. Skipped 0 file(s).
     [echo] Type 'seam restart' and go to http://localhost:8080/Acciones

generate:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out,
the catalog database name was wrong i had another name, using MySQL it needs to be the name of my database in caps and now it works.